# Android stream non static file image from URL

Tags: android, android-imageview

How to read an image from a URL like this in Android using ImageView:

[http://www.mphonline.com/ImgFile.aspx?TmpFile=D:\MPHLoc\ProdImg\9781740594943_s.jpg]

It would not return a normal static image stream.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

An Android emulator could not access resource from local drive

like `c: d: e:` as shows in your Que: `D:\MPHLoc\ProdImg\9781740594943_s.jpg`

You can refer [this](http://android-example-code.blogspot.in/p/download-store-and-read-images-from.html) if you want to download and display image from local

Comment: It's actually an image url & will display the image in the browser like this:

`data:text/html, <img src="http://www.mphonline.com/ImgFile.aspx?TmpFile=D:\\\\MPHLoc\\\\ProdImg\\\\9781740594943_s.jpg" />`

Just can't find any ways to display it in normal way because that image url will actually return unknown bytes instead of proper image type. Please advise.